# Change pairing dialog appearance in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have an Android app that pairs to a BLE device (which we also produce) and we are having some issues with the default Android pairing dialog:

[image: Pairing dialog]

The issues are:

- Our device does not need access to contacts or call history. Is it possible to remove that option? The pairing and our functionality will work regardless of whether the box is checked or not but our customers think they have to check it and have expressed concerns as to why we need that information. This option seems to have been added in Android 6.
- "Type the pairing code then press Return or Enter" doesn't make any sense as there is no pairing code and no input field. It would be nice to get rid of/change this text.

Is it possible to tweak the dialog via the app (preferably), or possibly by changes in the BLE device?

(I realize that the dialog might differ with different Android versions and/or manufacturers. The screenshot is from Nexus 5X with Android 7)

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to customize the dialog. What pairing options does your device support? passphrase / just works / ...

Comment: Our device does not require a passphrase.

Comment: Does it tell that the phone, when creating the connection for pairing? What are the supported pairing options regarding Bluetooth Core specification?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Bluetooth Core spec is not my area :) I've uploaded the SMP frame at http://tinypic.com/r/rvm32q/9

Comment: Hi @LoPoBo - I'm running into the same issue. Did you find a solution in Android? or does this require a firmware change to fix?

Comment: @NiallMccormack No, unfortunately I didn't find any solution in neither Android nor BLE device.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can't customize the apperance of the dialog in the app level, the only thing you could do is enable/disable the checkbox for allow the access to contacts or automatically accept the dialog and the pairing request using the`BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` permission.

But you can't use this permission if your app is a third party app (non-system app). To learn more, see Android API: [BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED)

Comment: If you configure the peripheral to use "just works" pairing then no popup will be shown.

Comment: @Emil Can you share with me how to set Bluetooth Pairing mode "Just works" in Android? I see no such method.

Comment: There is no API to set the pairing method in Android. You have to configure the remote device to do that.