# Change default Android BLE message when connecting to device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have an Android app that connects to a device via Bluetooth. When making this connection, a dialog is displayed with a field for the user to input the device PIN, and below that there is a message "Usually 0000 or 1234".

I'm trying to see how to change this message, however it is not defined by the app. From what I've researched this is from the cell phone itself ... is that right? I have not found any documentation about this message. Is it possible to change it? How?

Comment: Found this answer from 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662041/3768529
Did this change? Is there any official docs about this message?

Comment: It's the Bluetooth stack in the phone that shows this dialog. Why would you want to change it?